# Why did I fail a review audit in Triage by marking the question as 'Requires Editing'?

Tags: support, review-queues, disputed-review-audits, triage

I was reviewing posts and when I reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/10858543), the system stopped me and said **Review audit failed**.

But when I see the [actual question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34653247/1), it seems OK. Why did I fail this audit?

Comment: I can view the question (your second link), but the audit link says "question deleted".

Comment: Yes I am confuse.

Comment: Very weird. You're sure that audit was for that question?

Comment: @NateBarbettini - Yes. That was last question I reviewed and then System stopped me.

Comment: I'm not sure why. FWIW, I would review as "Requires Editing", too.

Comment: What are you actually asking? The question was posted (at least) twice by the same user. The first one was deleted a few minutes after posting by a moderator and the other is not deleted and was posted 3 days after the first one. Are you asking why the system believes that a question is deleted when it isn't? Answer: Two different questions. Or are you asking why a moderator has deleted the first question? Guess: There were multiple similar questions asked and the moderator cleaned them all up.

Comment: [Here's the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594845/are-ads-link-in-dfp-small-business-in-no-follow) to the actual question, it was deleted because it was posted twice by the same user. You happened to find the one that wasn't deleted.

Comment: @KevinBrown So this is a bad audit then, mistakenly taking a deleted dupe as a bad question?

Comment: Surely triage doesn't expect you to dig so deep to find exactly duplicates.  It's one thing if it's FP/LA where you're supposed to look for this sort of thing.  But triage is supposed to judge the overall state of a question quickly.  IMO this is an unfortunate (automatically chosen) audit.

Comment: @KevinBrown - But it really never show that question is delete while we auditing. So how can I judge? I felt that this question seems little ok and require editing so I flag that.

Comment: @ryanyuyu so... the only way to not raise suspicion with our robot overlords is to do our job poorly?

Comment: @HelpingHands, that is the point of an audit. For a question to become a "known bad" post, it has to be deleted. The audit does not show the question in it's actual state. A known bad audit must be downvoted and deleted with no upvotes. A known good audit must be upvoted with no downvotes or close votes. Both cases will (usually, apparently some cases are different though I've never seen it myself) set the score to zero while displaying it to you. You are supposed to judge the post based on the state that is shown to you. I agree that this one isn't a very good audit though.

Comment: It wasn't deleted *because* it was a duplicate - the first copy was deleted days before the second was posted. I suspect the second was posted in response to the first being deleted. The question is: why did a moderator delete the first instance?

Comment: So finally it is my mistake in audit OR audit system mistake that it displayed delete question?

Comment: @HelpingHands: Displaying a deleted question isn't a mistake; that is normal behavior for the audit system. The mistake was that the audit system assumed that the question was deleted because it was clearly and obviously bad - that doesn't appear to be the case here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Audits are picked automatically, not by a human. So a post that is deleted can be picked by the system to be an audit of a 'bad post', even if it wasn't deleted for being a *bad* post.

In this case, that led to an audit that criticised you for the right decision. This happens sometimes, bringing it to meta is the right call. It both lets you confirm that your decision was correct and draws attention to a questionable audit, so that it can be removed if necessary.

Comment: This issue of the system choosing bad review test questions seems to keep reappearing. Maybe something should be done before people stop doing reviews altogether.

Comment: @nwp I don't have a source on hand, but I remember seeing a response that said despite the visibility of bad audits, they are the exception and the vast majority of audits are good.

Comment: @nwp There's no reason to make a post about a successful audit. It was successful, what's there to talk about? Bad audits, on the other hand, need to be discussed *because* they are so rare.

Comment: @MageXy what do you mean successful? The OP was failed for marking the post as "Needs Editing"

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan I wasn't clear on my last post, sorry. The point I was trying to make is, successful reviews (ones where the user passes) are *never* brought up on meta because there's nothing to discuss. The user agreed with the system. However, a failed audit (such as OP's) *should* be brought up if the user disagrees with the system because then we can determine if the audit is a good one or not. Since failed audits/bad review questions are the only type of audits discussed on Meta, it *seems* like there are many more than there actually are.

Comment: @nwp bad audits are like plane crashes. You don't hear about every successful landing, so every time you hear about a plane crash, you attribute it to a rise in plane crashes. The fact is that there are just more planes in the sky. We don't have a meta question every time someone passes an audit, so you only notice when people fail one and disagree. Not only that, but not every failed audit meta post is actually a bad audit, a lot of them are good audits. That would be the equivalent to a plane having technical difficulties and performing an unscheduled landing.

Comment: @MageXy Ah, sorry I got notified about the comment and thought you were tagging me, not the other commenter. I reread and it makes sense now.

Comment: I didn't say the number of times the system fails to select suitable questions rises or are many, I said the problem keeps reappearing (every month or so). It is ok to say _"One per million tests selected is bad, we can live with that."_ If so someone should write a Q/A explaining the situation so further questions can be closed as duplicates. Or maybe there could be a `dispute audit`-button and we make yet another queue for disputed audits where people get to vote if the audit was wrongfully failed. Or maybe we just live with a meta-post every month or so.

Comment: The audit system is broken in many different annoying ways. Fixing this particular symptom will not make it suck much less, but an overhaul of the entire system should definitely target this one amongst the many problems it should fix. This overhaul is long overdue already.